# Setting up ArangoDB cluster wihout DCOS

Tags: database, graph, arangodb

I'm working on setting up an ArangoDB cluster in an Ubuntu machine based on these instructions :
https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/blob/b7cc85349c132f2ec7020dcddbd53e5bcfe12895/Documentation/Books/Manual/Deployment/Distributed.md

I keep getting the below error when i execute the first command in the above documentation with sudo. I ensured that all the directories
pointing to in the /etc/arangod.conf file has the required permissions. Please can you let me know if i'm missing something here.

Below is the error i get :

2016-08-23T07:29:52Z [26629] FATAL unable to create database directory: Failed to create directory [agency1] Permission denied

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command passes the database directory on the command line (agency1) and arangodb doesn't seem to have rights to create agency1 in your current working directory.

Either provide a proper working directory on the command line or specify one in the config file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to first change the directory to /var/lib/arangodb3 or whatever data directory you have set and then run the command.

Comment: Currently the directory is configured at /var/lib/arangodb3 in the arangod.conf file in /etc/arangodb3, i also made sure the permissions to /var/lib/arangodb3 is 777